# Please how do i redirect my login page to a homepage using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried using react router but i"m not getting it Please i need a better explanation

This is the link to my code

https://github.com/Focus247/Vehicle-Management.git

Comment: Hey mate, welcome. Please read this and fix your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask otherwise people will down vote you and your question will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple Login Page and use `useHistory` to redirect to Home Page or any page for that matter once Login is done.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

function Login() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const signIn = (e) => {
    // Do your authentication work
    history.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="login__right">
        <h1>
          <span>Log</span>In
        </h1>
        <h2>Email</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <h2>Password</h2>
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={signIn} type="submit" className="login__signInButton">
          LogIn
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

App.js will look something like this:

```js
import "./App.css";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Signup from "./components/Signup";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/signup">
            <Signup />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```